# cd into `/proc/xxx` works even if there is no process

Tags: proc

today I found something strange about the `/proc` folder. There is a PID (7825) which I cannot see as a running process via `ps`, also I cannot see the process id when I make `ls /proc` BUT I can see it with `ls /proc/7825` and also can cd into it. Here the outputs:

```
# ls /proc

...
dr-xr-xr-x   9 xxxxxxx         xxxxxxx             0 May 16 20:57 7812
dr-xr-xr-x   9 xxxxxxx         xxxxxxx             0 May 16 20:52 7820
dr-xr-xr-x   9 root            root                0 May 16 20:52 7836
dr-xr-xr-x   9 root            root                0 May 16 20:52 786
dr-xr-xr-x   9 xxxxxxx         xxxxxxx             0 May 16 20:57 7923
dr-xr-xr-x   9 xxxxxxx         xxxxxxx             0 May 16 20:52 7924
...
```

```
ps aux | grep [7]825

[EMPTY RESULT]
```

```
ls /proc/7825
attr    clear_refs  coredump_filter  environ  fdinfo   largest_task  make-it-fail  mem        mountstats  oom_adj        pagemap      root       setgroups  stat    syscall        timerslack_ns  weight
auxv    cmdline     cpuset           exe      gid_map  limits        map_files     mountinfo  net         oom_score      personality  schedstat  smaps      statm   task           uid_map
cgroup  comm        cwd              fd       io       loginuid      maps          mounts     ns          oom_score_adj  projid_map   sessionid  stack      status  time_in_state  wchan
```

Why is this PID available for `ls /proc/7825` but doesn't show up in the `ps` os `ls /proc`?

This is quite critical for my program, because I have to check if a certain PID (of the previous run) is still running (check if `/proc/[LAST_RUN_PID]/exe` exists). If so, I consider the previous run as "still-running". Today we had the issue, that the file `/proc/7825/exe` still exists (for hours) even if there is no program running.

Can somebody elaborate why/how this happens?

Comment: That's it:

```
# ps -AL | grep 7825
 7803  7825 ?        00:00:00 gmain
```

If you post this as question, I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: Just FYI: PID can be reused by other processes/fork/etc, so they aren't *unique* per se...so if you base your program/workflow around a specific PID instead of an actual program's PID (eg: grep the program name -> then grep the ID/PID of said program, which could have changed, etc) then you might see some other surprising thing...although you might be aware of that but just want to make sure you know

Comment: @NordineLotfi thx. This is a really good point and I have to consider this as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ps` on Linux takes its information from `/proc` so their information can't really differ. Even if incorrect pid/mount namespace setup means that `/proc` represents information not from the current pid namespace, `ps` will report the same incorrect information.

Here, it's likely that 7825 is a thread of some other process and you'd see it in the output of `ps -ALf`, where `-L` tells `ps` to report about all threads (light-weight processes), not just processes.

Comment: @StephenKitt, I'd expect it's possible if you switch pid namespace and not mount namespace. See for instance `sudo unshare -fp sh -c 'echo "$$"; ps'`

Comment: @StephenKitt, see also the `--mount-proc` of `unshare`(1). *Just before running the program, mount the proc filesystem at mountpoint (default is /proc).  This is useful when creating a  new
              PID namespace.  It also implies creating a new mount namespace since the /proc mount would otherwise mess up existing programs on
              the system.  The new proc filesystem is explicitly mounted as private (with MS_PRIVATE|MS_REC)*

Comment: Indeed, I was under the impression that `/proc` only cared about the pid namespace...

Comment: Ah, it looks up the pid namespace of the `/proc` `i_sb`.